# Is there a way to access a field from the state of a StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a field that changes in the state of a StatefulWidget but I want to access it in the widget itself.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Training();
  }
}
```

```
class Training extends StatefulWidget {
  const Training({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  String trainingToString(){
    return('people selected: ' + //Here I would need to access the variable from _TrainingState);
  }

  @override
  State<Training> createState() => _TrainingState();
}

class _TrainingState extends State<Training> {
  int peopleSelected = 0;

  void updatePeopleSelected(int peopleSelected){
    setState((){
      this.peopleSelected = peopleSelected;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

So I have the field peopleSelected and a function to update it in _TrainingState and when I call Training.trainingToString() I want it to print this field but I can't access the field through Training.

Is there a way you can do it or what would be some alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

you must to call this function you can use only for now

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
onTap: (){updatePeopleSelected()}
child: Container())
  }
```